# How to choose between two solutions where both seem to be correct?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Question to solve: $ y\sin (2x)dx - (y^2 + \cos ^2x)dy = 0 $ -----(i)

Writing (i) in exact form [$ M(x,y)dx + N(x,y)dy = 0$], we get

$y\sin (2x)dx + [-(y^2 + \cos ^2x)]dy = 0$ $where,M=y\sin (2x)$ and $N=[-(y^2 + \cos ^2x)]$

---

Since the given differential equation is exact, i.e, $∂M/∂y = ∂N/∂x = \sin (2x)$

it's general solution is given by 
$∫Mdx$ (with y constant) + $∫Ndy $ ("N" free from x terms) $=C$
My workout:

$∫Mdx$ (with y constant) = $∫y\sin (2x)dx$ = $\frac{-y\cos (2x)}2$

$∫Ndy $ ("N" free from x terms)$ = ∫-y^2 dy = \frac{-y^3}3 $

So, the general solution is $\frac{-y\cos (2x)}2$ + $\frac{-y^3}3 $ $= C$

But if we differentiate the general solution it does not trace back to original Differential Equation.
However if I simplify $ \cos ^2(x)$ as $\frac{\cos 2x+1}2$ I receive [$\frac{-y\cos (2x)}2$ + $\frac{-y^3}3 - \frac{y}2$ $= C$] as general solution and it does trace back to original differential eqaution. So, the problem is do i need verify everytime whether the obtained solution is correct or not, or both of the solutions are correct here?

Comment: I think checking the final solution is necessary, sometimes calculations have typos!

Comment: I believe there are no typos in either of the solution. But still your advice is useful.

Answer (score 1):

The following line in your original solution is wrong, which is the reason the answer you obtained is wrong (and thus doesn't satisfy the original equation):

> $\int Ndy$ ("N" free from x terms)$= ∫-y^2 dy  = \frac{-y^3}3$

A few lines earlier you stated (correctly!) that $N=[-(y^2+\cos^2x)]$, therefore the integral of $N$ is
$$\int N\,dy=\int[-(y^2+\cos^2x)]\,dy,$$
not what you set up above, as the function you put inside the integral is **not** $N$.

Comment: Is it not that while integrating "N", we should only integrate the terms in N which are free from x terms? And, N has $[−(y^2+cos^2x)]$, freeing it from x terms we are left with $-y^2$ only.